# Warning says Linq-To-Sql Expression is always false, but this is incorrect, why?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am getting a warning on the line noted in the comment in the code below. I am using Visual Studio 2015. I have 2 tables in a database, and querying them using Linq-2-Sql. The Linq Code performs a left join between the two tables on the companyID.

When run, the left join runs as expected, and I get all the values in TestTable1, but only records in TestTable2 where the companyIds match.

If the warning below were correct and the expression were always false, then the string "NULL" would never be assigned to value1. This is not the case, as when I run this I get "NULL" exactly when would be expected when doing a Left Join.

I use this pattern in many places in my code, and these warnings are everywhere, yet my code works fine with the NULL check I'm doing. The warning seems wrong to me. Am I missing something here?

t2.CompanyId is a database field of type INT. and also an int datatype in the linq-2-sql class, but somehow is still assigned null within the query.

```
    var db = new SandBoxDataContext();

    var result = (from t1 in db.TestTable1s

                  from t2 in db.TestTable2s
                    .Where(x => x.CompanyId == t1.CompanyId)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()

                  select new
                  {
                      //t2.CompanyId == null in line below is underlined with the warning!
                      value1 = t2.CompanyId == null ? "NULL" : "INT"

                  }).ToList();

    foreach (var rec in result)
    {
        Response.Write("value1 = " + rec.value1 + "<br>");
    }
```

Here is the warning

```
CS0472  The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'
```

Below is the generated SQL

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN ([t1].[CompanyId]) IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
        ELSE CONVERT(NVarChar(4),'INT')
     END) AS [value1]
FROM [dbo].[TestTable1] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TestTable2] AS [t1] ON [t1].[CompanyId] = [t0].[CompanyId]
```

Comment: Is `CompanyID` an `int` or an `int?` ?

Comment: an int in the database (a NOT NULL column) , and the Linq2Sql class (an int variable)

Comment: then it cannot be null as stated by the warning

Comment: you would think, but if you run the code you will see it can in fact be null

Comment: @Dancer321 It would be impossible to materialize `null` into an `int` - so that's not going to happen in your code. Also, since your column is marked `NOT NULL`, it would be impossible to have a null as a result. Though your query may be concerned with null, it would be impossible to have `CompanyID` return `NULL` either via SQL or in Linq2Sql.

Comment: @Rob that is true but L2S will happily crash internally if you cause a NULL to end up in a NULL property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is because comparing any `int` expression with `null` is always `false`.

This can be different in query expressions. The provider can translate to whatever it likes. Apparently, the C# compiler chooses to still warn you although this is a query.

I do not know what L2S translates this to. You state that it works so apparently the translation does what you want and the warning is a false positive.

I suggest you rewrite this to a form that makes the warning go away and increases code intuitiveness in the process:

```
value1 = t2 == null ? "NULL" : "INT"
```

Comment: Yes. your change removes the warning, and the code still works. The provider seems to treat DefaultIfEmpty() differently, not returning int's default value, but null instead.

Comment: Right, LINQ providers are very creative in translating to SQL.